# explicitly allocating resources on linux

Tags: linux

How can I explicitly allocate resources (from both cpu and physical memory) to a particular side e.g. Network or to a Process.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, processes will take as much of both CPU and network bandwidth as they can, relative to the rest of the system.  You can't, to my knowledge, explicitly give one process a certain amount of CPU speed like you can with virtual machines.

What you can do is adjust the scheduling priority of the process using "nice", though, as Crankyadmin mentioned. According to the "nice" scale, programs run from 19 (the least priority) to -20, the highest priority, and programs typically run at 0.

Notice that non-root users can only, by default, adjust their programs in the 19-0 range. Only the superuser can schedule priorities below 0 (adjust this default using ulimit in /etc/profile, but ONLY do it if you know what you're doing).

To run a new process at a specific nice level, do

```
$ nice -n 10 pwd
/home/msimmons
```

This runs the command at a nice level of 10. The $ indicates that it's a regular user. Here's what happens when you try to set a higher nice level:

```
$ nice -n -20 pwd
nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
```

Now, as root, we succeed

```
## nice -n -10 pwd
/root
```

To change the nice level of an already-running process, use "renice". So if I wanted my firefox session to go faster (dumb idea), I would do this:

```
renice -10 <firefox-PID>
```

Be careful doing this. Every time a process spawns a child process, that child process inherits the parent process's nice level. This means that if firefox (in my case) goes berserk, the system will probably go with it. That's why the maximum priority a user can change to is 0.

Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

ulimits and nice :D

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: @Muahmmad - Look them up.  If you read the FAQ, you'll find that this site is for professional system administrators, and that general questions like this belong on SuperUser.  Here you are expected to have a certain amount of resourcefulness in figuring things out.  Check a Unix or Linux manual or the man pages.

Comment: @David +1 You read my mind!

Comment: With all due respect to my esteemed co-serverfaulties, the goal of this community is, in my view, to function as a resource. To repeatedly point people asking questions does a disservice to them, in discouraging them from asking further questions, and to people visiting this thread in the future, because you have essentially contributed nothing of value except pointers to other resources (at best), which may or may not exist in 6 months or a year. Instead of answering with three words, take the time to explain and create something of value for now and the future.

Comment: Have to agree with Matt on this one. Either you should point the guy to a thread where this has already been answered, or you should give a better answer. Nothing I hate more than googling, and finding a thread where everyone clearly knows the answer, but isn't willing to tell the person asking the question because they feel he lacks moral fortitude or some such crap. If you don't think he deserves to know, just stfu...Giving a half-assed answer is just a way to show off.

Answer (score 0):

cpusets are a relatively new Linux feature, I haven't played with it yet, but it sounds interesting.  Here's some linkage:

http://www.bullopensource.org/cpuset/

http://oss.sgi.com/projects/cpusets/